# Is Developer studio (2.0.0) stable on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: wso2, eclipse-indigo, wso2-integration-studio

Is the latest release of developer studio (2.0.0) stable on Eclipse Indigo SR2 ? is Indigo supported with developer studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Developer Studio 2.0.0 with eclipse Indigo SR2 and I didn't find any issue related to the IDE stability yet.

Regards,
Gabriel.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended Eclipse version to use with Developer Studio 2.0.0 is Eclipse Helios SR2 (3.6.2).

Developer Studio has not gone through thorough testing on Eclipse Indigo but it did not encounter any issues while trying out with Indigo.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana